# Combined reflection and refraction

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

Suppose a plane mirror is half-submerged in another medium (say water) and light rays are incident obliquely on mirror at the interface separating two media.

My questions -
(a)- Will reflected rays suffer refraction ?
(b)- What angle will the reflected rays make with normal after reflection?
Will angle of reflection be same as angle of incidence (as given by law of reflection) ? [image: image showing setup of my question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rays are not "physical", they are mathematical/geometrical concepts to help us visualize what happens. Rays are the gradients of the propagating equal phase wave-fronts in the high frequency asymptotic regime. In a situation you are describing to understand what happens you should not just take a ray but a bunch of them, a pencil of rays. Assuming the ray shown is one of the gradient of the incoming plane wave-fronts, these should come parallel at the same incident angle both at the reflecting and at the refracting surface. Then you will immediately see that those rays *above* first will reflect followed  by a refraction, the rays "below" will first refract followed by reflection. Since this discontinuity is also affecting the wave-front itself from which the rays derive there will be no ray of such ambiguity, the single wave-front is split into two. This is the sort of question that is only resolved with a full wave propagation analysis that does not because it cannot involve "rays".